# Coral Growth Animation

Tags: animation, sculpting

I have a photoscan of a coral (existing mesh) which I would like to grow from a smaller version (almost nothing) to the exisiting scan. 
It's for my graduate film and it needs to be composited in real life underwater footage (using blackmagic fusion).
See the attached picture.

My Questions:

1. Do you have any suggestions for modifiers/tutorials I could use? Shapekeys was also a consideration.....
2. I would like to use a boolean modifier to let the white spikey corals on the left side grow from almost nothing to the full thing. 
   Any way I can export the boolean operation as alembic??? So that my compositing software can open it?

Thanks for any inspiration or input!!

[image]